# How do I set up Webpack, Angular 2.0, and Django together?

Tags: node.js, django, angular, typescript, webpack

I am currently trying a setup a webpack, angular 2.0 and django stack and trying to work with all of the parts together is a bit confusing.

I am using NPM to handle the libraries.

Here are the errors when I try to compile the typescript for loading with django:

```
                         Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
  main-71f084fe9f6c4015034a.ts   5.09 MB  0, 1, 2  [emitted]  main
   app-71f084fe9f6c4015034a.ts  23 bytes     1, 2  [emitted]  app
vendor-71f084fe9f6c4015034a.ts    3.6 kB     2, 1  [emitted]  vendor
    + 329 hidden modules

ERROR in /home/bischoff_s/Code/optim/typings/globals/webpack-env/index.d.ts
(176,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'RequireFunction'.

ERROR in /home/bischoff_s/Code/optim/typings/globals/webpack-env/index.d.ts
(225,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'module' must be of type 'NodeModule', but here has type 'Module'
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    }
}
```

My typings.json

```
{
    "globalDependencies": {
        "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
        "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
        "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
    }
}
```

My webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'vendor': './assets/js/vendor.ts',
        'app': './assets/js/index.ts'
    },
    entry: './assets/js/index.ts',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor']
        })
    ]
};
```

and finally webpack.dev.js

```
var path = require("path")
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name]-[hash].ts",
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with different typing from different webpack-env and node. here is the link for reference to the answer.

[TypeScript error on compilation with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727442/typescript-error-on-compilation-with-webpack/38729551?noredirect=1#comment64836068_38729551)