# TypeScript error on compilation with webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, typescript1.8

I am getting an error with typescript compilation and I have no clue where its coming from - I have tried many different combinations of tsconfig.json setups but I always get the same two errors from webpack-env.

```
(gec) ➜  optim ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
ts-loader: Using typescript@1.8.10 and /home/bischoff_s/Code/optim/tsconfig.json
Hash: 0e608742cc4dff532c9a
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 3182ms
                            Asset      Size      Chunks             Chunk Names
     main-0e608742cc4dff532c9a.ts   5.09 MB  0, 1, 2, 3  [emitted]  main
polyfills-0e608742cc4dff532c9a.ts  25 bytes     1, 2, 3  [emitted]  polyfills
      app-0e608742cc4dff532c9a.ts  25 bytes     2, 1, 3  [emitted]  app
   vendor-0e608742cc4dff532c9a.ts   3.63 kB     3, 1, 2  [emitted]  vendor
    + 329 hidden modules

ERROR in /home/guy/Code/optim/typings/globals/webpack-env/index.d.ts
(176,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'RequireFunction'.

ERROR in /home/guyCode/optim/typings/globals/webpack-env/index.d.ts
(225,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'module' must be of type 'NodeModule', but here has type 'Module'.
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed typings for webpack-env and node -- those two modules both have ambient declarations for **require** and **module**. Tsc is complaining that require/module can't be re-declared with different types (lines 176 and 225 of webpack-env/index.d.ts). Are you really using webpack-env typings? Try removing webpack-env/index.d.ts and see.

Comment: I deleted it and got the error (4,1): error TS6053: File '/webpack-env/index.d.ts' not found. What is webpack-env? It is not referenced anywhere in my webpack configs or node package.json

Comment: Look at the reference directive in your typings/index.d.ts -- it will reference the (now) missing webpack-env typings. Make sure it's also gone from your typings.json file, else a typings install will reintroduce it.

Comment: That did it, Thanks!

Comment: How to remove webpack-env? I didn't reference it in package.json nor typings.json.

Comment: This was a long time ago and typings.json is long deprecated.  I would remove typings.son all together, and reference typings directly from package.json using the "@types" prefixes.. Are you working on a legacy code base?

Comment: The other place to look would be the even more ancient reference directives at the top of any of your .ts files.